# Отсрочка вручения награды в конкурсе

Tags: поддержка, конкурс

Есть конкурс [Android. Запретить выход из приложения (Kiosk Mode)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669577/android-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-kiosk-mode) . Не один из ответом мне не помог, но возможно проблема в устройстве, на котором я тестировал свое приложения. В скором времени будет куплен новый планшет, который будет стоять в магазине. Можно отсрочить вручение награды пока мне не привезут новый планшет и я не попробую предложенные варианты решения проблемы на нем?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, модератор может отменить конкурс. Но отложить решение - вряд ли. Таким образом, ответ, скорее всего - Нет!